# Periodic auto update "html-div" and database in django

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-views

I'm trying to develop a website using Django. I have a model, which has to be updated periodically and readback and update it in html.

I have implemented this by calling a function in my "views.py", which will update the database, later it will read the database and update in the html. So, whenever i reload my page, it executes a function which gets all the necessary data, update the database, read it and update in "html". I just added the line `< meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"/>` to reload my page periodically in a interval of 10 seconds.

This is working proper, but it looks odd(when it is reloading). I know this shouldn't be the way it to be implemented. Much appreciated, If anyone can suggest a better way to update the database periodically and reload a part of the html.

Comment: Typically this is done with an AJAX call.

Comment: if possible, can you please share any references